# Lattice Theory and Topkis Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, order-theory, lattice-orders

Topkis Theorem states that: if $f$ is supermodular in $(x,\theta)$, and $D$ is a lattice, then $x^{∗} ( θ ) = \arg\max _{x ∈ D} f ( x , θ )$  is nondecreasing in $θ$.

It is not a simple concept for an undergraduate student from an economic department to understand. After struggling to understand what Theorem states, I am trying to find some examples of $f(x,\theta)$ that implies that $x^{∗} ( θ ) = \arg\max _{x ∈ D} f ( x , θ )$  is not nondecreasing in $θ$.

For example, I'm trying to find a supermodular $f (x,\theta)$ function, **not being increase differences** in $(x,\theta)$ with $D$ increasing in $\theta$, with **$x^{∗} ( θ ) = \arg\max _{x ∈ D} f ( x , θ )$ being non-increasing in $\theta$.**

Any help guys?